# Pyramids won't print properly on the console

Tags: java

I am trying to get the simple pyramid program and my coding looks quite good and works as well and after compiling it won't produce the expected output!

Below is my code:

```
package DataTypes;

public class Pyramids {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int x=0; x<=10; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<x; y++){
                System.out.println("*");

            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Expected output is

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

but its returning the same output in the below manner;

```
*

*
*

*
*
*

*
*
*
*

*
*

*
*

*
*
*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: The problem is that `System.out.println()` will always print you a newline after each `*`. When printing a `*`, you need to use the `System.out.print()` function to print it without a newline, then print a newline after each row.

Comment: Thanks Maximilian, realized it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("*");
```

use instead

```
System.out.print("*");
```

You don't want to change the line every time you print `*`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks YoungHobbitt :)